# How store data permanently in iOS with Cordova?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

Reading many sources online, I cannot find consistent information on which type of storage is permanent in iOS. Most say to use PhoneGap/Cordova Storage API. But the documentation mentions `window.localStorage` and makes no clear declaration that using any of the methods won't use localStorage and there's no mention of WebSQL,

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html

And this page http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/ , indicates that only webSQL is permanent on iOS. But how do I know which API will use WebSQL in Cordova?

Do I use `window.openDatabase()`? Something else?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confused by the description of Phonegap Storage API.

It depends how big your data is. You can use both WebSQL or `localStorage`. Both of them are considered as "persistent" by Cordova. Using either WebSQL or localStorage will store your data in cache.

> But how do I know which API will use WebSQL in Cordova?

Use  `var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "test", 200000);`

If your data is small, you can use localStorage which allows you to store data in key-value pairs. Thus, you'll define your database as

```
window.localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```

Comment: thank you. I know Cordova considers localStorage permanent but since ios 5.1, it is not

Comment: I've already used localStorage recently for ios7. It works. All data is saved permanently until you clear the cache manually. You might consider using localstorage for things like authentication. Note: don't mix up with sessionStorage which stores data as long as an app is open.

Comment: does localstorage save across restarts of the phone?

Comment: yes, the data is saved. Restarts don't affect anyhow.

Comment: Thank you, I have not had a chance to try this and confirm it. Once I do, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Does using the solution @Gurtej Singh mentioned keep the data even when clearing the browser cache?

Comment: @MatthiasMax , if you clear Safari cache, it will not affect application data storage. So data will stay there unless you explicitly delete application cache via Settings menu

Comment: Hi, thanks. I mean the iPhone -> Settings -> Safari -> Clear cache options. If I do that my app cache is gone as well. As I found out this was introduced in iOS 5.1.

Comment: A word of warning - at least on iOS, localStore get deleted by OS when device is low on memory.